# Orbital space clustering

Tags: quantum-chemistry, ab-initio-calculations, electronic-structure, orbitals

I am interested in how the orbital space of a system can be partitioned into clusters.

I read reading 'Cluster many-body expansion: A many-body expansion of the electron correlation energy about a cluster mean field reference': [J. Chem. Phys. 155, 054101 (2021)](https://doi.org/10.1063/5.0057752).

A couple of examples used in the paper are the $\ce{C_{2}}$ dimer and different polyacene Kekulé structures. Given a list of natural orbitals, how can one form sensible clusters?

For instance: consider a molecule with 5 occupied orbitals and 6 virtual orbitals:

```
mol.orbital_list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Would one partition the orbital space into different frozen clusters:

```
mol.cluster_1 = [0,2,4,6,8,10]
mol.cluster_2 = [1,3,5,7,9]
```

If so, how are the orbital clusters determined?

Comment: I gave +1 much earlier, but today just made the tags more appropriate and corrected the ChemJax formatting for the molecular formula you had in the question. In this case, you seem to be asking about something related to a 2021 publication about an MBE. While the MBE idea has been around for a while, I think it has had a revival in 2017 in a paper by Gauss and Eriksen, which came slightly after a similar idea was implemented by Zimmerman (also in 2017). Most users here won't know how the partitioning is done in that 2021 paper, without spending lots more time. I suggest you add a bounty!

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned. It can reopened if someone would like to provide an answer or OP addresses suggestions in the comments.